# Right to left edges in dot (Graphviz)

Tags: graphviz, right-to-left, graph-drawing

I'm trying to display edges going from right to left (i.e. backwards) using dot:

```
C <- A -> B
```

The best I could do was:

```
digraph {
  a -> b;
  c -> a [dir="back"];
  {rank=same;c a b}
}
```

..which is fine, except I don't like using `c -> a` when the edge is directed the other way.

So I wanted to share this solution (which didn't seem to be mentioned on SO) and check if I'm missing something obvious.

See: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:dirType

Comment: This doesn’t solve the problem that the rank of the nodes for the a-c edge still isn’t reversed relative to the graph, unless you write it `c -> a`. I wish one could just write `a <- c`. :/

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I have no alternative to your usage of dir, but i can make it slightly shorter, if you want horizontal alignment, use the [rankdir](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir) property of graph, to force direction from left to right.

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  a->b;
  c->a [dir="back"];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To make edges point backwards by default:

```
digraph {
  edge [dir="back"];
  a -> b;
  c -> a;
}
```

Then, override the default to point forwards:

```
c -> d [dir="forward"];
```