# Why does a top to bottom Graphviz dot graph get layed out counter clockwise?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Why does this code produce this graph?

```
digraph {
 rankdir = TB;
 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1;
}
```

[image: 1]

How can I get graphviz/dot to produce a clockwise direction like this?

[image: 2]

**Update**

This is the final graph I want to generate (afaik logically correct this way)

```
digraph {
  rankdir = TB
  start -> 1
  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1
  3 -> end
  3 -> increment
  end -> product
  {rank = same; 2; 3; increment}
  {rank = same; end; product}
}
```

Which produces this result

[image: 3]

While I want this

[image: 4]

Comment: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1; {rank = same; 2; 4}` also produces a counter clockwise graph while it could well be clockwise

Comment: Are you looking for an answer on how to do this the "correct" way? I'm 99% sure there is no "magic" instruction which automatically produces this output, and whatever else might be possible to achieve the desired output (invisible nodes etc.) will be a lot "hackier" than reversing edge directions. Graphviz's strength is to *automatically* layout graphs, and laying out nodes from left to right seems correct to me. If you need to manually fine-tune them, other tools may be more useful and faster to achieve the result.

Comment: Then I won´t search for a "correct" way anymore :) I just thought since everything is layed out counter clockwise (afaik) there has to be a setting to reverse that. But I´m really fine with reverting the edge directions if there is none.

Comment: An other related SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510784/right-to-left-edges-in-dot-graphviz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does this code produce this graph?

A directed graph puts its nodes on different ranks depending on their relations. Since 1 points to 2, it must be above 2, and since 2 points to 3 it gets to be above 3.
But since 3 also points to 1, the circle is completed - any of the 3 nodes could be on top. Graphviz simply puts the first mentioned node on top. Therefore, if you write instead:

```
2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2;
```

node 2 will be on top, and when using

```
3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3;
```

node 3 will be the top node.

Probably the layout engine `neato` would be more appropriate for this graph, producing a graph with a clockwise direction:

[image: neato layout]

If you absolutely must use the dot layout engine, the following dot code

```
digraph {
  rankdir = TB;
  1 -> 2;
  3 -> 2 [dir=back];
  3 -> 1;
  {rank=same; 2; 3;}
}
```

produces the desired output by changing the edge 2->3 into 3->2 and at the same time inverting the direction of the arrow.

Or, an other variant of the same technique, easier to explain: We reverse the order of *all* arrows (1->3->2->1), but display them backwards (dir=back), and force node 2 and 3 to be on the same rank:

```
rankdir = TB;
edge[dir=back];
1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1;
{rank=same; 2;3;}
```

This hack yields the following result:

[image: hack]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am using dottex in LaTeX. To be honest I have almost no experience in graphviz/dot/neato or whatever I need. If I write `layout=neato` the graph get´s all messed up.

Comment: But your last mentioned hack does the trick for me. While I know this may be not the "right" answer, it is all I need right now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the `[dir=back]` trick, that helped me create my desired graph layout in Sphinx (which uses the dot layout engine by default).

Comment: `[dir=back]` lets you do control system graphs where feed back paths are usually on the bottom with a reverse direction.  See: [tikz/latex example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/control-system-principles/).